# Rendering a partial with a jquery click on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, render, partial, renderpartial

I am new at rails. I have read almost all the posts opened in the past and I have tried so many things mentioned here, it still does not work. My rails version is 4.2. I am getting this error:

> undefined method `render' for #<#Class:.......

This is my link I want to click to render my partial:

```
<tbody>
    <%- @batches.each do |batch| -%>
      <tr>
        <td id="report-show-link"><%= link_to '#', :remote => true do %>
           Batch <%= batch.id %>
        <% end %></td>
```

**One of the things I read was keeping the `xxx.js.erb`, `xxx.controller.rb` and `_xxx.html.erb` file names the same and I did that.**
However, I am not sure, where to keep my `xxx.js.erb` file. If I put it to the same view file that I have my partial, rails won't recognize it. As of now, my `xxx.js.erb` file is under `assets/javascripts`.

**I have two methods (index and create) in my xxx.controller.rb**

I put

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render layout: false}
end
```

at the top of my create method.

And this is my jquery call:

```
    $("#report-hide").prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'batches')%>")
```

Once again; my files have the same names as: *_batches.html.erb, batches.js.erb, and bathces.rb* and I added **respond_to :js** on top of my controller. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The .js.erb file is a rendered template. It goes in the same folder as your main .html.erb file. Try using respond_with as opposed to respond_to and see if that helps you get the rendering going.

The probable reason you're getting the "undefined method 'render'" error is precisely because your .js.erb file is in the wrong location. JS code under app/assets is compiled *statically* and in that context you do not have access to Rails view helper methods (*render* being one of them). .js.erb code included in the view folder is rendered *dynamically* in response to a request and has access to the Rails view helper methods.

Comment: I changed respond_to to respond_with and now I'm getting **undefined method `respond_with' for....*** Once again, I put my js.erb file in the same view folder that I have my partial. My js.erb file will not work in javascript folder. It wont give any error but it wont do anything.

Answer (score 0):

If the controller/model is named Batch and BatchesController then the templates should be in `views/batches/*`. So:

`views/batches/index.html` and for js
`views/batches/create.js.erb`

And to clarify, the template name should be the same as the action method on the controller. So if you have BatchesController with an index method..  Then by default rails will call `views/batches/index.html`. And if you want to call a js template from your create method then putting the `respond_to` method like you did inside your BatchesController create method will call `views/batches/create.js.erb`